# Can the regeneration mechanism of lizards be used in humans?

Tags: zoology

Is there any mechanism or specific protein which helps lizards to regrow their tail? Can the mechanism of regeneration be used in humans to regenerate our limbs? Is there any other animal which has this kind of ability?

Comment: Here is a list of animals that can from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_(biology)#In_animals . I think the regeneration mechanism is due to stem cells and how cells differentiate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_(biology)#Tissues

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are some studies to find out your answer. Some of the studies claim that they have found a special enzyme and some say micro RNAs give salamanders the capacity of regeneration. But until now, humans couldn't use salamander's regenerative ability. Maybe you would like to know there is a mammal (african spiny mouse) with special regenerative capacities which include regeneration of its skin and cartilage without scarring.

References:

- ['Skin shedding and tissue regeneration in African spiny mice (Acomys)' Ashley W. Seifert,   Stephen G. Kiama,   Megan G. Seifert, Jacob R. Goheen, Todd M. Palmer & Malcolm Maden](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v489/n7417/full/nature11499.html)
- [Microarray analysis of microRNA expression during axolotl limb regeneration.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23028429)
- For further studies I recommend searching "salamander and regeneration", "african spiny mouse and regeneration" in pubmed ;)

Comment: Since you weren't able to get them on, I suggest you provide the name of the website(s), so that we know which ones to look at :)